# How do I collect critical-css for chunks of renderToNodeStream (React SSR)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering, critical-css

I want to implement `critical-css` for `React SSR`. There are many ways to achieve this but I'm interested particularly in this approach - I plan collect it on the fly after react renders the html. I have css on server and I want to inline only required css from it and load the rest asynchronously (I am not sure about performance but I saw production solution doing this with tools like purifyCSS, so I plan to give it a try and measure its performance)

**Problem #1 - Critical CSS extraction**

My SSR setup is based on [renderToNodeStream](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertonodestream) not [renderToString](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) so I cant compare html with css so easily - chunk might be just a piece of invalid html without closing tags. How do I parse classnames properly in this case efficiently? RegExp might be quite slow here I guess?

**Problem #2 - Inlining styles into html chunk**

My plan is to get the `chunk of html` that comes from `renderToNodeStream` and inline corresponding `css` into response - so it will be working similarly to [interleaveWithStyles](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/30dab74acedfd26d227eebccdcd18c92a1b3bd9b/packages/styled-components/src/models/ServerStyleSheet.tsx#L77) method of `styled-components`

Here's how chunk looks after `styled-components` processes it - `<style>` node might be inserted in the middle of `<svg>` - I suppose its not a problem as long as I will load full css eventually, but this doesn't feel safe as this node might be easily removed e.g. by react hydrate. So what would be correct way to **enrich html stream with inlined css**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

create a clone of readable stream that is returned by renderToNodeStream. convert it into string and purify with css to get the critical css.

Comment: converting a stream into a string will make the render synchronous. it is a pretty serious side-effect. if one was working with synchronous rendering, one might as well use `renderToString()`. further, how do you extract critical CSS? it won't happen by itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/theKashey/used-styles is working exactly as your desired solution:

- scans your build folder to find all styles you can use
- scans your HTML output collecting used styles (thus the name)
- inlines references to used style files as well as rules in a bulk (renderToString) as well as stream(renderToNodeStream) modes
- moves all injected code outside renderer markup just before applicating start allowing correct hydration.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is pretty bad and there are no examples. Since you managed to make the package, perhaps document it a little.